# Flutter - How to call an API every n minutes?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to call an API every n minutes. The data should be available across all screens. How can I implement this at app level. I am not using any state management tools.

```
        void main() {
      periodicSub = Stream.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 10))
          .listen((_) {
        ///fetch data
        someFuture =
            Future<List<someObject>>.delayed(
                const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () async {
          return someFunction();
        });
      });
```

someFuntions returns a list. I want a certain FutureBuilder on HomePage to execute whenever the list is updated.

Comment: Wrap this function in some global service that any widget can access. The most straightforward way (if perhaps not recommended way) would be to implement that service as a singleton.

Comment: How would I setState on the list returned from this someFunction ?

Comment: You can expose the stream itself so widgets that depend on it can listen via a `StreamBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using "https://pub.dev/packages/provider"

First create a Notifier:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  int counter = 0;

  CustomNotifier() {
    Stream.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 10)).listen((_) {
      ///fetch data
      Future<List<dynamic>>.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          () async {
        return someFunction();
      });
    });
  }

  someFunction() {
    counter++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Then you could use it like:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'notifier.dart';

void main() {
  final customNotifier = CustomNotifier();

  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => customNotifier,
        ),
        //You could add more providers
      ],
      builder: (context, _) {
        return const MyApp();
      },
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var customNotifier = Provider.of<CustomNotifier>(
      context,
    );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'someFunction runs this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '${customNotifier.counter}',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not using any state management tool. This can probably be achieved by using a stream and subscriptions.

Comment: Just to learn, any reason for not use them?